# Creating an offset dynamic range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to include the offset function into my VBA code, I currently have the offset in the name manager section of a seperate spreadsheet but would like to include it in the code. What I would like integrating into the code is included as a comment. Please could someone help with this?

```
Sub Unmet_Projects()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\turnbull\Documents\Global Unmet Demand\1-extract-Unmet projects.xls")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Unmet_Projects").Copy
x.Sheets("Unmet Projects").Range("L3").PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub



'=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),79)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the WorsheetFunction Offset returns a valid range; you can just use the formula in the `Worksheet.Range` or you could just use the defined name inside the `Worksheet.Range`.

Your code looks right.  You should test the formula to make sure that it is selecting the range.

[image]

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),79)").Copy

x.Sheets("Unmet Projects").Range("L3").PasteSpecial xlValues
```